# Как копировать директорию в каталог сборки при помощи cmake?

Tags: cmake

У меня в папке с сырками есть папка sound. Я хочу, чтобы при сборке эта папка со всем содержимым копировалась в каталог сборки. В идеале конечно, чтобы если папка с файлами уже есть, то копирование не происходило зазря.
Это должно работать как на linux, так и на windows.

Вроде такое можно как-то сделать через cmake install с указанием CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, но я cmake вообще не знаю.

Answer (score 2):

CMake с флагом `-E` работает в режиме универсальной утилиты командной строки. И в нем есть команда `copy_if_different`.

Т.е. вам нужно сделать `add_custom_target()`, который будет вызывать `${CMAKE_PROGRAM}` с этими аргументами.

Comment: add_custom_target(copy_files
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sound/leaf.wav ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/sound/leaf.wav
)  тоже не работает

Comment: configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sound/leaf.wav ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/sound/leaf.wav COPYONLY)  Лишь вот так у меня вышло скопировать один файл. Файлов мало, всего 5, думаю мне подойдет это решение.

Comment: `configure_file` вызывается на этапе конфигурации, а не сборки. Если вас это устраивает - можно использовать и этот вариант.